# Заменить подстроку в ключах массива

Tags: php, массивы, замена

Приветствую.

Есть задача следующего характера. Дан массив:

```
array('first-name' => 'Ivan', 'last-name' => 'Smirnov')
```

Необходимо преобразовать его в следующее:

```
array('first_name' => 'Ivan', 'last_name' => 'Smirnov')
```

Все, конечно, очень просто - заменить один символ на другой, но ограничивается это все тем, что циклы использовать нельзя.

Я плохо разбираюсь во всех этих функциях для работы с массивами, поэтому очень прошу помощи от Вас.

Заранее спасибо :3

Answer (score 2):

Отбой!

Решение нашел:

```
$new_array = array_combine(
array_map(function($key) {
    return str_replace('-', '_', $key);
}, array_keys($array)),
$array
);
```